# Guidelines on how to create link VS Code with a custom language's Debug Server coded in C++

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I've been working on small UI stuff in a VS Code extension and I think the documentation is great overall. But recently I've been asked to link VS Code to a C++ server so that it can automatically communicate with the c++ server. I've been trying for a few days with the help of Mock Debug but I can't make it work...
I don't understand what are "the core classes" or "core steps" in linking VS Code debug with an external DAP server.

I mostly tried to work in the package.json file. From what I understood what's needed :

- In package.json/contributes
  -> debuggers : is where you declare your debugger and link it to a language. Then you can setup the            custom configurations for launch.json.
  -> The debuggers/program parameter is intringing to me, it should give the path to the Debug Adapter executable... In my case would it be a typescript that opens a connection to the actual c++ DA server?

I'm sorry if this thread is disjointed, I'm quite a chaotic programmer (fancy saying for completely disorganised) but I really need a helping hand...

Comment: There are never clear guidelines (except the specification of DAP itself) but sample codes. If Mock Debug didn't tell you enough, try the source code of other extensions that have debugger integration. That's how people learned. You shouldn't expect too much assistance on such a topic here as only a small portion of VS Code extension authors have that experience.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the answer it does help in a way. For some reasons I didn't think of checking on github for "amateur" implementations of DAP.
I'm actually a junior developper and I hope I didn't sign up for to much with that project ahah

Comment: Just to be clear about LexLi's comment, it's not wrong to ask questions here about how to do reasonably small-scoped things with technologies that are poorly/partially-poorlydocumented. In fact- one of the founding goals of Stack Overflow was to solve that very problem.